# Etymology and meaning of the word "snog"

Tags: meaning, etymology, british-english

Having looked to urban dictionary, witionary, online etymology, dictionary.com, Wikipedia and wordfreaks.tribe.net, I have found a wide variance in the etymology and definition of the word *snog*.  I believe this to be a British phrase meaning simply kissing, but several of the above references push it to the level of making out.

Does the OED, or a some specific example in common usage provide any insight or guidance to differentiate the connotation?

Comment: Dunno if it's relevant that I'm a Brit, but I've never heard it used to mean anything other than *kissing*. But since *fondling/feeling up* will sometimes be going on at the same time, and might not be explicitly mentioned, I suppose it's possible to assume *snogging* covers all related activities short of full sex. I just don't happen to make that assumption, and I don't think most Brits do either.

Comment: @FumbleFingers So would you say "I snogged my mother goodnight" or "I snogged my grandmother at Christmas"?

Comment: @MετάEd: Me personally, no! And I can't find any instances of *"I snogged my brother/sister/father/mother/etc."* in Google Books, so I guess the people who do that kind of thing maintain a discrete silence (or whatever you call it when you avoid *writing*, as opposed to *saying* something!" :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Right. My belief is that "snogging" definitely is about kissing, but kissing specifically in a sensual way and with petting. It means both less and more than kissing.

Comment: @MετάEd: Of course. I didn't mean to imply *kissing* and *snogging* are exact synonyms (a closer one might be *necking*). But in general, I don't think many speakers who are accustomed to using and hearing the word necessarily expect it to include *petting* at all. I certainly wouldn't confuse ***heavy** petting* with *snogging*. So, like OP, I'm not keen on [TheFreeDictionary's](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snogging) *caressing, cuddling, fondling, hugging*. Maybe that's American usage, I don't know. I thought the word was basically a Briticism anyway.

Comment: 'Snog' is onomatopoeic for the sound Brits make when kissing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you being British matters to me, in that I was looking for some idea of the "common" usage of the word.

Comment: @Joshua: I often mention my nationality because it may be relevant. In this case, I've just checked OED myself to discover that although (per Hugo's answer) they cite an early usage by one C. H. Ward-Jackson saying *Comes from India*, they clearly attach no credence to it (they say the origin is "unknown/obscure", but suggest links to old German/Dutch words). Whatever - I think it's a perfectly commonplace Briticism known to almost everyone. Apart from anything else, there're been a TV show called [Snog, Marry, Avoid](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b00htyc7) for years.

Comment: ...but I don't know why you don't at least announce your nationality on your [User Page](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/14070/joshua-drake). I'll feel pretty silly saying all this if it turns out you *are* British!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Done.  I asked because I've heard it around, most recently in one of the Harry Potter movies. (Yes, I'm very late to the party.)

Comment: @Joshua: Top man. Now I see you're from US Midwest, it's worth mentioning that there are hundreds of minor changes in the US versions of Harry Potter books (*jumper* becomes *sweater*, *trainers* become *sneakers*, the US text has many more commas, etc.) So my guess is the publishers assume most US readers know what *snogging* is (or they'll pick it up from context). The activity can be quite *risqué*, but the word itself isn't really. I believe it's still fairly common among young people, particularly teenage girls, and older people for whom it's reminiscent of long-past sexual awakenings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [phonosemantics](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/#mono) of [**sn**-initial words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sn.pdf) includes two body-part foci, of which one is

- **Nose, Mouth, and Respiration** (*snooze sniff sneeze snort snore snuff*)

*Snog* 'kiss', and its attendant courtship metaphors, like flirting, fits right into this frame. It's not a part of my idiolect, however, and I didn't include it in [my database](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/monosyl.zip). So the numbers in [the link](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sn.pdf) are off by one; with the addition of *snog*, the page should read

- **SN- 39** out of **45** coherent assonances

  - **A. Nose (20**

Thank you.

Comment: I'm up for that! Apparently [the best known examples (of phonesthemes) are English initials such as fl-, which is expressive of movement and characterizes a family of words, as in:](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/Phonestheme.htm) *flap, flare, flee, flick, flicker, fling, flip, flit, flitter, flow, flutter, fly, flurry, flounce, flourish, flout, flail, flash, flex, flinch, flock, flop*. But ***sn-** / nose* is second on their list. You might ***snuggle*** while *snogging*, though.

Comment: That depends on [who's](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/#mono) doing the best knowing; **[st-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/style.pdf), [br-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/WomenMen&BristlyThings.pdf)** and **[kl-](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf)** are also impressive.

Comment: haha - I was telling a friend earlier today that I distinctly remember the lecturer in my (short) linguistics course 40 years ago telling us language was just arbitrarily-assigned symbols. Apart from a few onomatopoeic words, which he downplayed on the grounds that *other* languages don't usually match to our *quack, moo, woof,* etc. And now I've just read (some of) your WomenMen&BristlyThings, where you start off by saying *sound symbolism...is one of those myths teachers in Introductory Linguistics are at pains to debunk*. Onwards and upwards - to infinity and beyond!

Comment: Am I'm reading this correctly that the term would mean kiss primarily, assuming that nose touches nose?

Comment: As far as I know, it means 'kiss'. Talk to the native speakers.

Comment: @Joshua: *Snogging* is definitely more than just "kissing" - it's almost as close as you can get to full sex without going below the neck! Beaten to the top slot there only by [eating his/her face off](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22eating+her+face+off+at+Alex's%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). So, yes - nose would definitely touch nose.

Answer (score 3):

Eric Partridge, in his *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*, offers these definitions:

> **snog** *n.* A flirtation; a courting: esp. among beatniks: since ca. 1959 (Anderson.) Ex:
>   **snog** *v.* To flirt, or to court, esp. in *be* or *come* or *go snogging*: beatniks', adopted, ca. 1959, ex general s. (Anderson.)

Richard Spears, in *Slang and Euphemism* lists

> **snog** to neck; to kiss and caress. For synonyms, see FIRKYTOODLE [British slang, 1900s]

He defines *firkytoodle* as "sexual play, sexual foreplay" and lists dozens of synonyms, including *canoodle*, *love up*, and *spoon*.

Answer (score 0):

The OED says of *snogging*:

> Etymology:  Origin unknown: compare *snug v*.
>
> Engagement in light, amorous play, esp. kissing and cuddling.

Their earliest quotation is:

> 1945   C. H. Ward-Jackson *Piece of Cake* (ed. 2) 56   *Snogging*, courting, running around with the opposite sex. Comes from India. Thus, ‘On my leave I'm going up to the hills for a bit of snogging.’ Also used as a verb.