# Can the verb "wonder" simply take an object?

Tags: grammar, verbs, objects, transitivity

In [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96203/the-origin-of-canoodle), the questioner states

> I wonder the origin of the word.

Can *wonder* take a simple object like that? Or should it be *wonder about* or *wonder at* or something similar (or something else)?

*Wonder* can certainly be used in other constructions:

> - I wonder if that’s right.
> - I wonder whether we’re dreaming of butterflies or a butterfly dreaming we’re awake.
> - I wonder about that whole Mayan thing.

But all of those are not **just** a simple object. Even

> I just wonder.

...generally indicates wondering *at* something or *about* something, which might not be specified.

[ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wonder) specifies *wonder* as a verb with no object, but the quoted use is quite deliberate.

Should we simply take this as a poetic use?

Comment: A quick glance shows that around half of the questions posted here are ungrammatical, and more than half of the text associated with them contains grammatical errors. This suggests that perhaps they are not the best possible models to imitate.

Comment: "Something made me jump.  I wonder what."

Comment: "I wonder what [it was]." @Henry, this is an indefinite clause, not a true object.

Comment: I think you have to _wonder **about**_ something. *_I wonder that._ is definitely ungrammatical, but _I doubt that._ is definitely grammatical.

Comment: *I wonder will it rain tomorrow* does of course mean the same as *..whether it will rain tomorrow*, but is not quite the same construction. Could that be the basis of an answer, I wonder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In *“I wonder the origin of the word”*, *origin* appears to be the direct object of the verb, with *wonder* being used transitively.

OED has examples of this use, which is equivalent to the modern ***wonder at***:

> †**3. a.** *trans.* To regard with wonder; to marvel at: often implying profound admiration (cf. *wonder* n. 7c). *Obs.*
>
> 1593   B. Barnes *Parthenophil & Parthenophe* 18 :  If she be silent euery man in place With silence wonders her.
> 1821   C. Lamb *My First Play* in *Elia* 1st Ser., :  I knew nothing, understood nothing, discriminated nothing. I felt all, loved all, wondered all.

However the modern ***wonder about*** does not appear to have its equivalent in an obsolete transitive form:

> †**3. a.** *trans.* To regard with wonder; to marvel at: often implying profound admiration (cf. *wonder* n. 7c). *Obs.*
>
> **3. b.** *impers. pass.* it is to be wondered = it is to be wondered at (1d). Now *rare* or *Obs.*
>
> †**4.** To affect or strike with wonder; to cause to marvel, amaze, astound. (See also 1f) *Obs.*

Even defintion 1b is listed as intransitive:

> **1. b.** with clause expressing the motive or object of wonder.
> 1846   W. Greener *Sci. Gunnery* (new ed.) 133 :  We wonder the parties did not take a patent for the discovery.

This is quite close to the original form, but again is *wonder at*, not *wonder about.* The meaning *wonder about* is listed as “usually with clause” rather than transitive with an object:

> **2.** Usually with clause: To ask oneself in wonderment; to feel some doubt or curiosity (*how, whether, why,* etc.); to be desirous to know or learn.
>
> *a*1616   Shakespeare *Winter's Tale* (1623) iii. iii. 69   What haue we heere? Mercy on's, a Barne?... A boy, or a Childe I wonder?

That citation appears to use *a child* as the grammatical object of *wonder* in the meaning *wonder about*. But the definition is still intransitive.

OED does have a note

> ***I wonder*** is often placed after a question which expresses the object of curiosity or doubt; e.g. ‘How can that be, I wonder?’ = I wonder how that can be. Also ***I wonder!***, colloq. exclamation expressing doubt, incredulity, or reserve of judgement.

So it appears that *wonder* can take an object (albeit in an obsolete use) if the meaning is ***wonder at*** but **not** if the meaning is ***wonder about***.

Answer (score 7):

No, it cannot. The only instances the Oxford English Dictionary gives of the transitive use of *wonder* are obsolete.

Comment: True, although the 19th-century citation is not **too** far back, nor sounds too odd: “1821 Lamb *Elia* Ser. ɪ. *My first Play*, ― I knew nothing, understood nothing, discriminated nothing. I felt all, loved all, wondered all.”

Comment: Reduced that-clauses are very common, and if  "I don't wonder that he had a heart attack" is allowed, which I'm sure is true, then the elided version "I don't wonder he had a heart attack" is also. Some would call this (elided) construction a syntactical direct object construction (though I wouldn't).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't see how the conclusion follows from the premise. Who says that you can just drop the word "that" in all possible sentences that might include it? "I think that Bob is here." Good. "I think Bob is here." Also good, works. "I love that so many came." Good. "I love so many came." No, doesn't work. "I think that is an apple." Good. "I think is an apple." Definitely no. Etc.

Comment: There's nothing unusual about "wonder" here. Many similar words work the same way. You can think about the moon, but you can't think the moon. You can dream about falling, but you can't dream falling. Etc.

Comment: @Jay There are internet examples for the zero complementiser after 'wonder': eg from [The Works of the Rev. Jonathan Swift](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=694NAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=%22wonder+he+had+the%22+-%22Small+wonder%22+-%22any+wonder%22+-%22no+wonder%22&source=bl&ots=iIry6-WIYM&sig=OE6YwqRgwo8eLCDf5t0GQtFGMDs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=mLQRVNHzKYfy7AaukIHYDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22wonder%20he%20had%20the%22%20-%22Small%20wonder%22%20-%22any%20wonder%22%20-%22no%20wonder%22&f=false): 'I wonder he had the face to talk so'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think that's one of the "obsolete constructions" Barrie was referring to. You see that in old books but not so much today.

Comment: @Jay There are plenty of similar [zero complementiser] constructions in use, especially with a negative verb. "I wonder he didn't marry her"; "I wonder he didn't stay"; "I wonder he didn't cash in on the journals"; "I wonder he didn't mention it" (first two pages of a Google search for "I wonder he didn't"). But as I said, I wouldn't class what follows 'wonder' as a true DO.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hmm, I only find 8 hits in Bing on "I wonder he didn't". One is an ad where they fill in your search term, so that doesn't count. (I once was doing some research on the history of slavery and typed in "black slaves". I got back a hit from a certain shopping website with the title "Best prices on black slaves!") Two of them are quotes from Charles Dickens, fitting the idea of obsolete usage. Two are translations from Japanese, which I would not expect to be good English grammar. And the other three are "I wonder if he didn't ..." which is what I would expect in modern English.

Comment: @Jay If we're straying into the acceptability of 'I wonder he didn't ...', I've used it, I've heard it used, but I would consider it at least semi-formal. Have you checked the various examples on Google? Also see Jon Hanna's previous answer.

Answer (score 5):

It's allowed but uncommon these days (it was more common once). I wouldn't be surprised if some regional forms had it heavily, but I would advise avoiding it as unidiomatic yourself.

Interestingly, it's more common in the negative, where it means that something was expected: "I don't wonder he had a heart attack, he lived on fried food and smoked forty a day". Here "I don't wonder that..." would still be more common, but the first form I give wouldn't be unheard of.

Answer (score 1):

"To wonder" is an intransitive verb, which means it cannot be followed by a direct object.  It must be followed by an indirect object.

An example:

> *I wonder the moon.

*The moon* is used as a direct object, but the sentence does not make sense.

> I wonder at the moon.

*The moon* is preceded by the preposition *at*, so it becomes an indirect object and the sentence is grammatical.

In addition, if a clause follows *I wonder*, the verb remains intransitive, as a clause is not a direct object. Example:

> I wonder whether he will arrive today.

Answer (score -2):

Yea, verily!  This question wonders me!

In serious response: Yes, 'wonder' can be used with an object, but only when used as a synonym for 'amaze', not in the sense of 'to be curious or introspective about something'.

Comment: Not my downvote, but it's generally expected that unusual uses be supported by documentation. I might unaccept the accepted answer and write my own (now that I have found a canonical reference).

Comment: Inasmuch as "unusual" is synonymous with "archaic", yes.